# Php backend 'ssh2_connect' service return error 503 with react router frontend

Tags: php, reactjs, rest, ssh, react-router

thanks in advance for your help,

I want to get all the directories and their content from a distant server. So i made a php server hosted at the same level as a react application. (cf. the following screenshot)
[foldersTree](https://i.stack.imgur.com/VSzgx.png)

ajax.php contains all my api services which i can access without problem. The only service that doesn't work is the ssh service to get the folders from the distant server written as following :

```
case 'ssh':
        $port = 22;
        $reponse='hello';
        $connection = ssh2_connect($host, 22);
        if(!$connection) die("Connection failed");
```

So this service always return the index.html of my react application instead of 'hello'.
Like this :

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
    <html lang="fr">
    
<head>
    <meta charset="utf-8" />
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1" />
    <meta name="theme-color" content="#000000" />

    <title></title>
    <script defer src="/static/js/bundle.js"></script>
</head>

<body>
    <noscript>You need to enable JavaScript to run this app.</noscript>
    <div id="root"></div>

</body>

</html>
```

Maybe something is wrong with my proxy, or the ssh2_connect change the proxy, or the react application url goes in front of the backend idk... but i still can access my others services in the same file.

I can access my react pages using this url:
http://localhost:3000/
And to access my service i'm using this url:
http://localhost:3000/root/backend/json/ssh

Could you please enlighten me ? Thanks once again

---

**Update 1** to paste more code:
Thanks for taking a look at my problem, here is more code and procedure to reproduce the case :

Configuration first ->

I work on a mamp local serveur. The server is hosted on port 80. There is no more configuration on it.

My *.htaccess* looks like this:

```
ErrorDocument 404 /page-non-trouvee.html

Header set Access-Control-Allow-Origin "*"
Header set Access-Control-Allow-Methods "GET,PUT,POST,DELETE"
Header set Access-Control-Allow-Headers "Content-Type, Authorization"
Options FollowSymlinks 
RewriteEngine on
 
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI}::$1 ^(.?/)(.)::\2$
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ - [E=BASE:%1]

RewriteRule ^$ %{ENV:BASE}accueil/ [L,R=301]

RewriteRule ^([a-z,A-Z,0-9,-]*)/$ %{ENV:BASE}index.php?target=$1 [L,QSA]
RewriteRule ^json/([a-zA-Z]*)/$ %{ENV:BASE}index.php?target=json&action=$1 [L,QSA]
```

Backend ->

My *index.php* looks like this :

```
try{
    if(!isset($_GET['target'])){
        $_GET['target']=''; 
    }   

    switch($_GET['target']){
        case 'json':
            require './controllers/ajax.php';
        break;
        
    }
}catch (Exception $e) {
    echo 'Exception reçue : ',  $e->getMessage(), "\n";
}
```

My *ajax.php* called by index.php looks like this :

```
switch($_GET['action']){
        case 'getAllUsers':
            require './controllers/userController.php';
        break;
    ...
    case 'ssh':
        $host = "the host i try to connect"
        $port = 22;
        $reponse='hello';
        $connection = ssh2_connect($host, 22);
        if(!$connection) die("Connection failed");
    break;
}
    if(empty($json)) 
        $json = json_encode($reponse,JSON_UNESCAPED_UNICODE);

    

    require('./views/json.phtml');
```

Finally my *json.phtml* :

```
header("Content-Type: application/json");
echo $json;
```

Now the frontend ->

To create the react app, i used the command *npx create-react-app* and i put all the folders into the frontend folder :[FrontendFolder](https://i.stack.imgur.com/lV0wN.png).

The module i installed that manage the urls is react router v6 : https://reactrouter.com/docs/en/v6/getting-started/overview.

So my *index.js* is like this :

```
import React from "react";
import ReactDOM from "react-dom";
import { BrowserRouter, Route, Routes} from 'react-router-dom';
import './index.css';
import { App } from "./routes/App";
import { Provider } from "react-redux";
import store from './app/store';
import { StyledEngineProvider } from "@mui/material";

ReactDOM.render(
  <React.StrictMode>
    <BrowserRouter>
        <Provider store={store}>
            <StyledEngineProvider injectFirst>
                <Routes>
                    <Route path="/*" element={<App />} />
                </Routes>
            </StyledEngineProvider>
        </Provider>
    </BrowserRouter>
  </React.StrictMode>,
  document.getElementById("root")
);
```

`npm start` is used in the folder frontend to lunch the react application

Now how to reproduce the case ->

I'm using postman to test my services so i access getAllUsers by this url :

http://localhost:3000/fps/root/backend/json/getAllUsers

Which return all the users in ma database as expected.

Now i try the other url :

http://localhost:3000/fps/root/backend/json/ssh

Which return my `index.html` page from react : [index.html folder location](https://i.stack.imgur.com/gPR8g.png)

which looks like this :

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="fr">

<head>
    <meta charset="utf-8" />
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1" />
    <meta name="theme-color" content="#000000" />
    <meta name="description" content="Configurateur produits FPS " />

    <title></title>
    <script defer src="/static/js/bundle.js"></script>
</head>

<body>
    <noscript>You need to enable JavaScript to run this app.</noscript>
    <div id="root"></div>

</body>

</html>
```

instead of just "hello" from the ajax.php file

When i comment the line *$connection = ssh2_connect($host, 22);* from *ajax.php* i get my response (hello), otherwise it just return the above file *index.html*

Here is the ssh2_connect documentation :
https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.ssh2-connect.php

Moreover, when i set the action of ajax.php to 'ssh' manually and type *php ajax.php* in my folder *controllers*, i well get the informations. It appears that react or react router does a redirection and i can't figure out how to fix it

I hope this time i gave enough informations, tell me if you need something else. Once again thank you for your help !

---

**Update 2**

I think i'm in the case of this post:
[React-router URLs don't work when refreshing or writing manually](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27928372/react-router-urls-dont-work-when-refreshing-or-writing-manually/36623117#36623117)

React router redirect me to its routes when ssh2_connect does its thing

---

**Update 3**
I was well in the above case, the fact is, when php execute *$connection = ssh2_connect($host, 22);* this line fail and return an error 503 which wasn't catch by the *.htaccess*. Now it is and i get an error 503 without more details when i try to access my service using postman, but still work when i call it from my command line

Comment: You may need to paste more code and what you expect with your code. The code you paste has no relation with your output.

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.